# wp_editor ignore User setting for "Disable the visual editor when writing"

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg, wp-editor

I am using the wordpress function wp_editor() in wordpress. This displays a WYSIWYG editor, like the ones for creating posts and pages.

I am using this function in a custom plugin. When i first used it, it didn't show the two buttons to switch between visual mode and text mode, but only text mode.

After some searching i found out that it was a user setting. If you go to wp-admin->users->edit user, you will see the setting: "Disable the visual editor when writing" with a checkbox.

Once i unchecked that, it worked for that user. However, i am searching for a way to show the buttons even when the user has the disabled visual editor setting set to true.

So my question: How can i use the wp_editor() function in a plugin to display the wordpress WYSIWYG editor with buttons for visual and text mode, regardless of the current user setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. The function wp_editor() calls a class which checks the user setting for "Disable the visual editor when writing" with the function user_can_richedit(). So adding a temporary filter can overwrite this:

```
<?php


add_filter('user_can_richedit','richEditOverwrite',999999);
wp_editor($content,$editor_id);
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'richEditOverwrite' );

/**
 * Overwrites user_can_richedit()
 * @return bool
 */
function richEditOverwrite(){
    return true;
}
?>
```